# CSS How to align text when preceding element has a word break

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to align some numbers to be on the same line, however the preceding line, because of a word break, I cannot get them all to be aligned.

I've tried position: absolute but I also want to make this work with browsers with small screen sizes, is there anyway to approach this?

Problem I'm dealing with

[image]

The way the code is structured is something like this

```
<h5>Header</h5>
    <div class = "row">
        <div class = "column">
            <label>Planned</label>
            <a href="">10</a>
        <div>
        <div class = "column">
            <label>Bought</label>
            <a href="">12</a>
        <div>
        ...
```

Comment: Would it be acceptable to use a second row for the numbers, or do you need the text and numbers to be consecutive?

Comment: Please post more of your code with CSS

Comment: Can you include the full markup and the css associated with it ?

Comment: You could simply use a table for this

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

Use flexbox, and it's better to use `span` than `label` unless in a form.

```css
.row {
  display: flex; /* flex row */
  width: 200px; /* example */
}

.column {
  flex: 1; /* grow */
  display: flex; /* flex */
  flex-direction: column; /* column */
  justify-content: space-between; /* push items */
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <span>Planned</span>
    <a href="">10</a>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <span>Planned Planned</span>
    <a href="">10</a>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <span>Planned Planned Planned</span>
    <a href="">10</a>
  </div>
</div>
```